# All idempotent elements in $M_n(F)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, modules, idempotents

I know that every idempotent matrix is diagonalizable. Thus, I can search diagonal matrices for all the idempotent elements. In this case, $(n,0), (n,1),..,(n,n)=2^n$ diagonal matrix can be obtained. It means there are $2^n$ idempotent elements in $M_n(F)$. But, I need to show that just $1$ can be on the diagonal. I can not understand why just $1$?

Could someone help me out please?

Comment: Can you specify in what field are you working?

Comment: Generally I need to find it for every field

Comment: @Wai You should also probably take a look at our $\LaTeX$ crash course: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117

Comment: If $E$ is idempotent and $A$ is invertible, then $AEA^{-1}$ is also an idempotent (check it if you don't see it right away). See @rschwieb's answer for the same. For example, if $2\neq0$ in $F$ then
$$\frac12\pmatrix{1&1\cr 1&1\cr}$$ is an idempotent similar to $E=diag(1,0)$. If $F$ is infinite, there will be infinitely many idempotents (belonging to $2^n$ similarity classes).

Comment: Can you please explain if $F$ is infinite then how can one conclude the existence of infinitely many idempotent matrices?

Answer (score 2):

> But, I need to show that just 1 can be on the diagonal. I can not understand why just 1?

This is all very elementary. Suppose $T$ is an idempotent transformation and $\lambda$ and eigenvalue with eigenvector $x$.

Then $\lambda^2 x=T^2(x)=T(x)=\lambda x$.  From $(\lambda^2-\lambda)x=0$ you know $\lambda^2-\lambda=0$, and hence the eigenvalues are solutions to $\lambda(\lambda-1)=0$.  Either $\lambda =0$ or $\lambda =1$.

> It means there are $2^n$ idempotent elements in $M_n(F)$.

Yes there are *at least* that many elements... but not *only* that many. There could be infinitely many more.

The final step (which I'm not sure you're seeing) is to recognize that after you've written down all the diagonal matrices with all combinations of $0$ and $1$ in the set $E$, then you can conclude that the set of all idempotent matrices is

$\{u^{-1}eu\mid e\in E, u\in GL(n)\}$

where $GL(n)$ denotes the set of invertible matrices of $M_n(F)$.

That is, idempotent matrices aren't *diagonal* they are just *diagonalizable*, that is, similar to a diagonal matrix (of a certain type.) <s>There are $2^n$ similarity classes, but each of those classes can (when $F$ is infinite) contain infinitely many members.</s>

Apologies: a correction was pointed out to me by loup blanc:  the similarity classes of the $2^n$ idempotents overlap!  This is because the idempotents which share the same number of $1$'s are similar. Since there are $n+1$ possible counts for the number of $1$'s, there are only $n+1$ equivalence classes.

Comment: Why are we writing all the diagonal matrices with all combinations of 0 and 1 in the set E.I didnt understand this .Like that we are taking just matrices which have 0 and 1 elements

Comment: @Wai I'm writing it in $E$ so I can use it in the set-builder notation I wrote above.  Otherwise it makes the description awkward.  "Like that we are taking just matrices which have 0 and 1 elements" I don't know what you mean by this. The set I described is certainly not "the matrices which have 0 and 1 elements"

Comment: I got it.Thank you for your help, it was really helpful:))

Comment: @rschwieb , there are not $2^n$ similarity classes but only $n+1$.

Comment: @loupblanc Oh, of course, you're right.  The thing that's important is the signature of the idempotent, not the idempotent itself.

Comment: @loupblanc Should be fixed now: thanks for saying something.

Comment: Çan you please explain how the number of similarity classes is $n+1$ and not $2^n$. And how is this connected to the signature of the matrix?

Comment: @SaikatGoswami yes, the signature. Diagonal matrixes with equal numbers of ones and zeros are mutually similar, so a lot of the $2^n$ combinations are similar to each other.

Comment: @rschwieb I have studied that signature of a matrix means (m,n) where m: no. of +ve eigenvalues, n: no. of -ve eigenvalues. So the signature of a diagonal matrix above is of the form (n,0). Right?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, now I get your point. Why only the signature is important.

Comment: @SaikatGoswami well it’s not really signature. Signature is an invariant of bilinear forms. I just mean the number of $1$’s.  There can be from 0 to n 1’s, and that covers everything.

Comment: @SaikatGoswami I dunno, start with this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113899/discussion-between-saikat-goswami-and-rschwieb).

Comment: @rschwieb I thought a lot about how 2 diagonal matrices with the same number of 1's are similar. By straight computation, I could find a solution for the case of  $2x2$ matrices. But not for the general case. Please help me out here.

Comment: @SaikatGoswami I responded in the chat you started

Answer (score 1):

An idempotent matrix represent a projection onto a certain subspace, hence the only eigenvalues that can appear are 0 and 1. A diagonal matrix that represent a projection can have only ones as nonzero elements.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful.I missed a part about Eigenvalues. Well, the way I found 2^n idempotent elements in Mn(F) is right?

Comment: No, because there are infinite matrices similar to a given diagonal matrix of that tipe. Think about an orthogonal projection on a single vector, you can choose infinitley many vectors where you can project, but the resultant matrix will be always similar to the matrix with only a 1 on the diagonal.

Comment: I am alittle bit confused now .I didnt understand exactly.

Comment: Mn(F) is generated by idempotents. So, idempotents are basis . Did you mean like that ?

Comment: You are counting only the diagonalized matrices,  even non diagonal matrices can have the property of being idempotent. Think for example at the 2x2 matrix with all entries equal to 1/2.

Comment: Yes,I know. Thus, I used "every idempotent matrix is diagonalizable". So, can not ı think like all dioagnals?

Comment: Projections give another useful way of looking at the situation.

Answer (score 0):

We consider the algebraic set  $Z=\{A\in M_n(\mathbb{C});A^2=A\}$. The best indicator of the size of an algebraic set is its dimension, i.e. the number of complex parameters on which its elements depend.

Since there are only a finite number of similarity classes, it suffices to find a class of maximum dimension.

A class is in the form $\{P^{-1}diag(I_p,0_{n-p})P;P\in GL_n\}$. Its stabilizer (for the conjugation action) is the commutant of $diag(I_p,0_{n-p})$, that is,  a vector space of dimension $p^2+(n-p)^2$.

The minimum for $p$ is obtained when $p\approx n/2$ and is $\approx n^2/2$. Then the required maximum dimension is $\approx dim(GL_n)-n^2/2=n^2/2$. More generally, one has

$\textbf{Proposition.}$ Let $Y=\{A\in M_n(\mathbb{C});p(A)=0\}$, where $p$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ with simple complex roots.

Then $Y$ is an algebraic set of dimension $\approx n^2/2$.

$\textbf{Remark.}$ i) The previous proposition applies to symmetries $S^2=I_n$.

ii) For comparison, a nilpotent matrix depends on many more parameters because the dimension of their set is $n^2-n$.